# Specific currency for value in formula that is referencing a currency field

Tags: formula

My org wants to set up an automatic account "tiering" based on the value of an opportunity. It should look at the value in the currency field called "Amount" on the opportunity, and based on that value it should choose an appropriate value for the picklist "Tier" on the related account. I have created the below formula in process builder which works, but it doesn't take currency into account.

`IF([Opportunity].Amount >= 100000, "A", IF([Opportunity].Amount < 50000, "B", IF([Opportunity].Amount < 10000, "C", null)))`

We use a bunch of different currencies depending on what region the opportunity is in, so what I would like to do (if possible) is to be able to set the values in the above formula as "EUR", and have Salesforce automatically convert the value in "Amount" to EUR before checking the above formula. Is this possible to achieve somehow? I have found some solutions on Google where I'd have to hardcode a conversion rate into the formula, but that's less than optimal.

Comment: can you not use a `CASE(CurrencyIsoCode,'EUR',IF expr,'USD',diff If expr, ...)`?

Comment: You can't use dated exchange rates in formula fields, only the static rates (defined in Setup) via the CURRENCYRATE function.  Note also that if you have many different currencies, you may exceed the formula size limit if you try cropredy's suggestion.  You may need to search AppExchange for a 3rd party app that can provide date exchange rates and also allow you to build the formulas you need.